# System State Backup on Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, backup, backup-restoration

I wanted to do a one-time full server backup of the Domain Controller. However, there was almost 1 TB of data to backup. So I am just doing a System State backup instead, which is less than 5 GB.

At our company we use domain logins. Is backing up the system state of the DC enough to ensure that all the user accounts are safe?

Will I be able to recover Active Directory with all the same users, groups, privileges, ect...?

Comment: To answer your question; Yes. My question is why do you have 1TB of data on your DC and how are you backing up that data?

Comment: I don't know why. I am a little new to the field. I suspect it is because our company's shared drive is integrated with the DC. The DC lists the shared drive as one of its servers.

Answer (score 3):

The system state backup (when done on a Domain Controller) includes AD schema/data. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727048.aspx) for more details.